# How to add dependencies to a Debian control and dsc file and configure options to a rules file that depends on the distro in question?

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I am trying to build a bleeding-edge package (with new upstream versions packaged within hours) for Vim on Debian 7/8 and Ubuntu 12.04/14.04./16.04, the problem I keep running into is that Ubuntu 12.04 is having issues related to Python 3, so I would like to remove the python3 dependency for Ubuntu 12.04 and remove the configure options related to python3 in the rules for Ubuntu 12.04 only also. So the packages for Debian 7, 8 and Ubuntu 14.04/16.04 build with Python 3 support (and the corresponding python3 build dependencies), but the package for Ubuntu 12.04 builds without python3 support and without python3 build dependencies. Is this possible?

If you are wondering whether this is necessary, [here](https://build.opensuse.org/package/show/home:fusion809/vim-debian) is my Open Build Service package providing Vim on Debian-based platforms (so you can see my packaging files there) and here is my build log (showing the errors related to Python 3) for building on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 http://paste2.org/wf59EzfM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way of changing build-dependencies during a build, for the very simple reason than package builds first download the build-dependencies, then run the build. If the build decides to change the build-dependencies, it's too late. The only modifiers you can use for build-dependencies are architecture specifiers, and build profiles, neither of which apply here.

What you can perhaps do, is build-depend on `python3` and `python`, then decide during the build (in `debian/rules`) how to configure the package, and adapt the various files that are used to calculate the binary packages' dependencies.